# Named Entity Recognition on Text with python

Tags: python, nltk

I am extracting disease, treatment,body part infected from cancer stories written by patients, The approaches of doing this generally fall into three categories: lexicon-based, rules-based and statistically based, I am trying to use nltk but i do not have a corpus at the moment,Kindly advise me on the best way forward. Currently i am thinking of using lexicon-based approach,creating lexicons of all the categories, disease,treatment but it will be tideous.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I'm afraid it's not clear how anyone can answer your question. If you don't have a corpus or other relevant resources, my advice is to spend some time on google and find some.

Comment: I am new to this field and currently trying to get a corpus for cancer types,treatments! this then can help me create a dictionary, but i dont know if this is the best way to do it

Comment: Spend some time on google? Your question is too vague to be answerable.

Comment: What you need is not a dictionary, though; you need to train a classifier. Look at the NLTK book, it's all there. (But you do need to find a corpus if you're going to train anything.)